# Where to find UWP Segoe MDL2 icons in image format?

Tags: image, xamarin, icons, uwp, xamarin.forms

It's not possible to use the **"Segoe MDL2 icons"** glyph icons in Xamarin.Forms for UWP. Where can I find these icons in image format so I can refer the image files. I've looked and couldn't find anywhere. Anyone?

These Icons are to be used in Xamarin forms ToolbarItems.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Save" Clicked="SaveClicked" Order="Primary" Icon="save.png" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure you have legal rights to use those icons on other platforms.

But if you want, on Windows 10:

1. Open Character Map app
2. Select Segoe MDL2 Assets font.
3. Choose and copy any icon.
4. Open any photo editor(eg. Paint.Net)
5. Select text tool
6. Select Segoe MDL2 Assets font
7. Paste your icon
8. Select size, color etc.
9. save as png

Also you can use [Metro Studio](https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) to get png icons from any font.